# KQL lookup principal

Tags: azure-active-directory, kql, azure-data-explorer

I can query details about myself using the builtin functions:

- [`current_principal()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/current-principalfunction)
- [`current_principal_details()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/current-principal-detailsfunction)
- [`current_principal_is_member_of()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/current-principal-ismemberoffunction)

Using other control commands, I can see other AAD principals (usually identified by guid). e.g. [`.show commands-and-queries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/commands-and-queries)...

[image: commands-and-queries]

...shows a service principal. I can get more details about this service principal if I search the AAD ID in the Azure Portal like so...

[image: azure portal service principal]

...but is there a builtin KQL function or workaround I could use to get details about this and other service principals in-line with my ADX admin queries?

Answer (score 0):

Kusto does not provide arbitrary Graph lookup APIs.

You should do this via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)